# calc word optimization problem

Tags: calculus, optimization

a power line runs north-south. Town A is 3 miles due east from a point a on the power line, and town B is 5 miles due west from a point b on the power line that is 9 miles north of a. A transformer, on the power line, is to accommodate both towns. Where should it be located so as to minimize the combined cable lengths to A and B?

Comment: Where are you having trouble with this problem?  We could solve it, but it ostensibly your homework.

Comment: With the whole problem. I'm not even sure how to start it.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  let the power line run along the $y$ axis and put point $a$ at the origin.  What are the coordinates of $A$ and $B$?.  The transformer is at point $(0,t)$.  What is the distance to each town?  Add them up, take the derivative with respect to $t$, set to zero. Or use the fact that the shortest distance between two points is a straight line.

Comment: How would I find the coordinates of A and B?

Comment: @gina:  If $a$ is $(0,0)$ and A is three miles east of that...

Comment: so would it be (0,3)?

Comment: @gina:  no, I said north was along $y$.  3 miles east would then be $(3,0)$  point b is then $(0,9)$